# Where can I find TeX Live after installing via Homebrew?

Tags: texlive, macos

I installed TeX Live via Homebrew (4.1.17) on my Mac (macOS Sonoma 14.1): `brew install texlive`. Now, I'd like to use this TeX Live distribution in IntelliJ IDEA with the plugin TeXiFy IDEA.

When creating a new LaTeX project, I'm asked to select a project SDK. Unfortunately, I don't know where to find the TeX Live distribution.

Homebrew uses the path `/opt/homebrew`. Therefore, I tried to find the right path to TeX Live there, but I had no success, neither with the directory `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/texlive/20230313_2` (which is shown after running `brew install texlive`) itself nor with any other subdirectory/executable in `/opt/homebrew` I tried. IntelliJ IDEA always says "Could not find [path I choosed]/bin/*/pdflatex".

Where can I find the TeX Live distribution installed by homebrew?

Thank you for any help!

**EDIT:** As @DG' said, installing TeX Live on macOS via Homebrew can be done by installing "MacTeX without GUI": `brew install mactex-no-gui`. MacTeX is then installed at `/usr/local/texlive/2023` and TeXiFy finds it. This solves my problem.

Comment: I don't know what a `TeX Live SDK` is supposed to be, but (a) the TeXiFy IDEA Wiki says that it finds your distribution automatically after a restart and (b) you can find the actual path with `which pdflatex` witch returns something like `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`on a Mac

Comment: @DG' By "TeX Live SDK" I actually mean the TeX Live Distribution (I wrote "TeX Live SDK" because IntelliJ IDEA/TeXiFy asked me to select an SDK). The output of `which pdflatex` is `/opt/homebrew/bin/pdflatex` – but when I select this, the above mentioned error occurs. I was wondering what will happen when I skip the step of selecting the TeX Live distribution, so I tried. It works! TeXiFy has found my pdflatex. But unfortunately, I still don't know where I can find the distribution which I need to select when creating a new project.

Comment: Just wondering: why homebrew and not just MacTeX? Most LaTeX awere editors on Mac assume MacTeX (and its location: `/Library/TeX/texbin/` as mentioned above). Plus MacTeX is the easiest to install. Plus remember that you are likely to be ,issing a lot of LaTeX stuff after running `brew install texlive` (at least if it is just like the `apt` original)

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE @PascalZillmann Like said daleif, I'm using MacTeX on my Mac OS X without issue. I don't use IntelliJ IDEA, but I'm quiet sure it will work better.

Comment: I think Homebrew simply runs the MacTeX installer, so your main texmf tree will be `/usr/local/texlive/2023` and the binary directory (which is a symbolic link) should be `/Library/TeX/texbin` (although in that case it's odd that `which pdflatex` returns what it does.)'

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you. I had a look on the directories you mentioned, but none of them exist on my Mac.

Comment: @PascalZillmann (a) try debugging homebrew (`brew doctor`), (b) reinstall texlive (`brew reinstall texlive`), or (c) remove texlive and install mactex (`brew rm texlive && brew install mactex-no-gui`)

Comment: @DG' Thank you! (c) worked for me – IntelliJ IDEA now finds TeXLive. But what are the differences between `texlive` and `mactex-no-gui` (except that the latter is handled as a cask instead of a formula)? Are there any differences in the features of `texlive` and `mactex-no-gui`? (Homebrew's description of `mactex-no-gui` says that it is a "Full TeX Live distribution without GUI applications" which sounds to me being basically the same as `texlive`.)

Comment: mactex is texlive with all the workarounds needed to run seamlessly on osx. cf. https://tug.org/mactex/

Comment: @DG' Oh, okay. I couldn't imagine that there is such a big need for workarounds so that TeX Live runs seamlessly on macOS.

Comment: "workarounds" is probably not the best term. :) MacTeX seamlessly installs the correct binary for your hardware, and sets up a very nice set of symbolic links that makes switching distribution years easy, and allows you to have a single path to the binaries. It also is a signed app, which means that you don't have problems with Apple's increasingly draconian security protections.

Comment: @AlanMunn - That is _exactly_ the definition of workaround I had in mind ;)